# Git Hub not working with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2022

I have created a project on my work computer and use github within visual studio 2022 as the source control.
When I get home, I open the same project on my home computer and get the latest changes. Again using VS2022 and git hub.

However, the changes are not appearing on the home computer's "Git Repository" nor the "Git Changes" window.  They both show no incoming files.

I have checked, and I'm on the same main branch and have the same github url at work and at home. I also refreshed the "git repository" at home but no new files to download showed up.

I ended up running a git console command "git pull origin main" which updated my home PC with all changes that it was meant to.

My question is why isn't my home VS2022 showing me or telling me that there are downloads for me.   Is there a setting that I am not aware of?

Any assistance appreciated.
Erick

Comment: You'd need to run `git fetch` to get the remote changes in your local repository. `git pull` will perform a fetch under the hood., then merge the changes.

Comment: The question wasn’t about which command to run.  Visual studio 2022 has a link and window that shows incoming and outgoing changes.  I knew I had incoming changes because I made them.   Why didn’t visual studio show that I needed to do pull/fetch ? Without this indication it is not possible to use the VS built In Fetch and Pull commands as VS thinks there are no changes.  VS should check on start-up and periodically against github repository

Comment: Those changes won't show up until you fetch them to your local repo.  You can use the fetch option in Visual Studio just fine. Visual studion doesn't periodically check against GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [@jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079/jessehouwing)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76802520/git-hub-not-working-with-visual-studio-2022#comment135398310_76802520), running `git remote update` will actually fetch changes, if there are any. This allows you to see whether changes have been made, without immediately merging them with your `main` branch. One benefit of `git remote update` is that you get to see exactly which branches have been changed.

However, `git diff origin/main` might be more of what you're looking for. If you're currently set on the local main branch, it'll show you all the differences between your local version and the version in the cloud.

Unlike fetching, you'll be able to use `git diff` more than once (since you won't be able to fetch the same changes twice) to prove that the remote is different than the local version. Just in case you forgot whether you already ran the command, etc.

Comment: The git diff will also only see the changes that have been fetched to the local repo.

Comment: `git remote update` is the equivalent of `git fetch` in most cases.

Comment: @jessehouwing I agree, you need to run `git remote update` (or `git fetch`) first. But, let's say you forgot whether you already fetched changes. Fetching changes again won't show you updates that you already fetched, so running `git diff` can still be helpful for these cases. I wasn't trying to compare `git remote update` with `git fetch`; I just use `git remote update` and I wanted to expand on what you said.

Comment: So again, using the developer Command Prompt console works, It's the vs2022 git and github that isn't working.  The 'Git Repository" on each PC's only shows changes in the remote repository made on by that PC.  For some reason the remote git repository isn't showing changes being made on a different PC.  Running the commands will fix that.  But shouldn't VS2022 indicate that there have been changes made by others, so I know to perform a Pull/Fetch to download them. VS2022 doesn't appear to be checking the remote GitHub repository for changes.

Comment: @ErickTreetops Well, you *will* need to use the equivalent of these commands in Visual Studio. Is locating the functions within the application your issue? When you say, "VS2022 doesn't appear to be checking the remote GitHub repository for changes," what do you mean by that? Every time you fetch, it checks for changes.

Comment: @ErickTreetops What do you mean, "GitHub [...] isn't working"? Sounds like your problem is just in Visual Studio and has nothing to do with the way GitHub is functioning.

Comment: Visual studio 2022 seems to be unaware of changes being made to the remote repository by other developers.   The “Git Repository window in VS2022 has a list marked as “incoming”.  You would think it would check periodically for remote repository changes or at least check when the refresh button is pressed or when you first open Visual Studio.   The only way I was able for the changes to show up in this list was to open the developer console and run a git command.

Comment: @jessehouwing Sorry I replied to the wrong person. I'll edit my comment.

Comment: @ErickTreetops Is there something specific that led you to believe it would fetch automatically? If you click on the dropdown arrow besides "Incoming" in Visual Studio, it says "There are no incoming commits. Please fetch to get the latest commits from your remote branch." If you want them to be in your incoming list, then you need to click on the blue button that says "fetch." Unless you have a particular use case where you need to fetch automatically on a schedule (it would be uncommon), this should be fine for you.